# Serving webpack assets to an ASP.NET app?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webpack, http-proxy, webpack-dev-server

I doing the front-end for this ASP.NET 4 project (I know almost nothing of .NET) in which when I press F5 or Ctrl-F5 the app serving is the Index.cshtml on http://localhot:52724 but my webpack config serves assets on http://localhost:8000 when I run `npm start`. It is a React front-end.

In the index.cshtml file if I refer to my JS using the following everything is fine.

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/assets/app.js"></script>
```

But I would prefer to serve it as

```
<script src="assets/app.js"></script>
```

on the same port, if possible. Or maybe there is a better approach to this?

Here is the base.js (being imported in the webpack.config.js)

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var port = 8000;
var srcPath = path.join(__dirname, '/../src');
var publicPath = '/assets/';

var additionalPaths = [];

module.exports = {
    additionalPaths: additionalPaths,
    port: port,
    debug: true,
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/../dist/assets'),
        filename: 'app.js',
        publicPath: publicPath
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './src/',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        hot: true,
        inline: true,
        port: port,
        publicPath: publicPath,
        noInfo: false
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            actions: srcPath + '/actions/',
            components: srcPath + '/components/',
            sources: srcPath + '/sources/',
            stores: srcPath + '/stores/',
            styles: srcPath + '/styles/',
            config: srcPath + '/config/' + process.env.REACT_WEBPACK_ENV
        }
    },
    module: {
        preLoaders: [{
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            include: srcPath,
            loader: 'eslint-loader'
        }],
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.sass/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded&indentedSyntax'
        }, {
            test: /\.scss/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader?outputStyle=expanded'
        }, {
            test: /\.less/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!less-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.styl/,
            loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!stylus-loader'
        }, {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=8192'
        }, {
            test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'url-loader?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff'
        }, {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
        }]
    }
};
```

And here is the dev.js (being imported in the webpack.config.js)

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var _ = require('lodash');

var baseConfig = require('./base');

// Add needed plugins here
var BowerWebpackPlugin = require('bower-webpack-plugin');

var config = _.merge({
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './UI/src/index'
  ],
  cache: true,
  devtool: 'eval',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new BowerWebpackPlugin({
      searchResolveModulesDirectories: false
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        'fetch': 'imports?this=>global!exports?global.fetch!whatwg-fetch'
    })
  ]
}, baseConfig);

// Add needed loaders
config.module.loaders.push({
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
  loader: 'react-hot!babel-loader',
  include: [].concat(
    config.additionalPaths,
    [ path.join(__dirname, '/../src') ]
  )
});

module.exports = config;
```

and the server.js file

```
/*eslint no-console:0 */
require('core-js/fn/object/assign');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');
var open = require('open');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), config.devServer)
.listen(config.port, 'localhost', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('Listening at localhost:' + config.port);
  //console.log('Opening your system browser...');
  //open('http://localhost:' + config.port);
});
```

Comment: A bit confused - if you're doing the _front end_, why would you need to run a different app server? If the front end is on some-other-server, then _typically_ ASP.Net would be something like an API (Web API, WCF, etc.) that provides services/data to your (separate) front end app.

Comment: In your example for the js script, that works because it's no different from obtaining _externally_ hosted libraries (e.g. Google/ASP.net CDN for common js libs). In your _intent_ to serve from a _local resource_ then it stands to be served by the _local app server_ (ASP.Net/IIS is the local app server for the ASP.net app)

Comment: Just did a quick readup on webpack (I'm your opposite, no nothing about it), so it seems, it's a "bundler/dev tool" (but I could be terribly wrong). ASP.Net/Visual Studio has it's own bundling system and other tools/plug-ins to help assist in the development phase (watching files/changes, "compiling" scripts, css/less/etc)....

Comment: ASP.NET bundler it's bad... I really don't like it, that's why I'm trying to build some kind of solution to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

You could take a look at this source that I working on

```
// webpack.config.js
var webpack = require('webpack');
var extractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var clean = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
var webpackStrip = require('strip-loader');
var path = require('path');
var IS_DEBUG = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

var webpackConfig = {
  entry: {
    home: [
      './src/entries/home',
      './src/styles/entries/home'
    ],
    vendor: [
      // Styles
      'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap',
      './src/styles/core',
      // Scripts
      'bootstrap',
      'jquery'
    ],
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/bundles',
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/Content/bundles/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.css', '.scss']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel',
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        cacheable: true,
        query: {
          presets: ['es2015'],
          retainLines: true,
          cacheDirectory: true
        }
      },
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'eslint-loader', exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/ },
      { test: /\.css$/, loaders: ['style', 'css'] },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass'],
      },
      { test: /\.woff2?(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/font-woff" },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=application/octet-stream" },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "file" },
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: "url?limit=10000&mimetype=image/svg+xml" }
    ]
  },
  sassLoader: {
    includePaths: ['./src/styles'],
  },
  devtool: IS_DEBUG ? 'cheap-source-map' : 'source-map',
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      $: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin(
      'vendor', '[name].js'
    )
  ]
};

if (IS_DEBUG) {
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  );

  Object.keys(webpackConfig.entry).forEach(function(item) {
    if (item === 'vendor') {
      webpackConfig.entry[item].unshift('webpack/hot/dev-server');
    } else {
      webpackConfig.entry[item].unshift('webpack-hot-middleware/client');
    }
  });
}

// Production
if (!IS_DEBUG) {
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new clean(['bundles']),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      }
    }),
    new extractTextPlugin("[name].css")
  );

  webpackConfig.module.loaders.forEach(function(item) {
    if (item.test.test('.scss')) {
      delete item.loaders;
      item.loader = extractTextPlugin.extract('css!sass');
    }

    if (item.test.test('.css')) {
      delete item.loaders;
      item.loader = extractTextPlugin.extract('css')
    }
  });

  webpackConfig.module.loaders.unshift(
    { test: /\.js$/, loader: webpackStrip.loader('debug', 'console.log') }
  );
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

I'm creating a server with hapijs to serve the assets and make it work the HRM plugin. Also there's a proxy for the ASP.NET to get HTML and Controllers responses.

```
// webpack-dev-server.js
import { Server } from 'hapi';
import H2o2 from 'h2o2';
import yargs from 'yargs';
import Webpack from 'webpack';
import WebpackPlugin from 'hapi-webpack-plugin';
import webpackConfig from './webpack.config';

const argv = yargs.argv;

const isNumeric = n => !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);

if (!isNumeric(argv.port)) {
  console.log(`Port must be numeric`);
  process.exit(-1);
}

const compiler = new Webpack(webpackConfig);
const server = new Server();

server.connection({ host: 'localhost', port: 6789, labels: 'proxy-server' });

const assets = {
  publicPath: webpackConfig.output.publicPath,
  hot: true,
  noInfo: true,
  quiet: false,
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 6790,
  stats: {
    colors: true,
  },
};

const hot = {
  log: console.log,
  path: '/__webpack_hmr',
  heartbeat: 10 * 1000,
};

server.register([
  {
    register: H2o2,
  },
  {
    register: WebpackPlugin,
    options: { compiler, assets, hot },
  },
], error => {
  if (error) {
    return console.error(error);
  }

  server.route({
    method: ['GET', 'POST'],
    path: '/{path*}',
    handler: (request, reply) => {
      if (/^Content\/bundles\/[A-Za-z0-9\-]+\.css/.test(request.params.path)) {
        const response = reply('// This is a fake CSS content... :)');
        response.type('text/css');
        return response;
      }

      return reply.proxy({
        host: 'localhost',
        port: argv.port,
        passThrough: true,
      });
    },
  });

  server.start(() => console.log(`Server running on ${server.info.uri}`));
});
```

Here's the [repo](https://github.com/byoigres/aspnet-mvc-webpack-proxy-assets) of the project, it's not finished yet but the proxy functionality it's working good.

To start the server in dev mode run `npm start -- --port=[asp-net-project-port]` and build for production with `npm run build`

All the output files will be put in `Content/bundles` folder, so the files `home.js`, `vendor.js` and the dependent assets will be there. Then in razor you can just link the javascript or styles to that files.

Comment: Just out of curiosity/interest (I know nothing about webpack), what would be the impetus of this workflow in the context of ASP.Net/VIsual Studio ecosystem? I get it from an ASP.net web API perspective, just struggling on any other (re: having to proxy controller responses)....

Comment: I totally forgot about what the OP is asking, to replace `<script src="http://localhost:8000/assets/app.js"></script>` to `<script src="assets/app.js"></script>`, what I'm doing with webpack it's just generating the assets (js, css, fonts, images) from dependencies (npm or bower) and putting them in `Content/bundles` directory, so with razor we can just use `<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Content/bundles/app.js"></script>` directly.

Comment: Cool beans - thank you! I think in ASP.net 5 (I haven't tried), this can be done natively. I see some semblance of that in Cordova projects today (where tooling builds all the dependencies/packages - npm _not_ Nuget). Thanks again!